# Можно поместить MySQL и HTTP-сервер в разных странах?

Tags: база-данных

Получится ли поместить БД на виртуальном сервере в Голландии, а вебсервер, CMS, PHP на VPS расположенном в России и чтобы эти сервера были между собой связаны?

Comment: Можно. Но зачем так?

Comment: Чтобы копия данных была защищена, но возможно это слишком сложное решение и я мало разобрался и + часть аудитории находится в Европе. а часть в РФ

Comment: Дополните лучше вопрос про «защищенность», что именно от нее надо и в чем не разобрались.